# NPM 7 - Pass Flags to Script

Tags: node.js, npm

In NPM prior to version 7, we were able to pass arbitrary flags to a package.json script using dollar-asterisk:

```json
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "build": "npx pkg-bin build $*"
}
```

For example, if the above script is executed like this:

```sh
npm run build --OVERRIDE --versionNumber=1.2.3
```

The `OVERRIDE` and `versionNumber` flags were accessible via `process.env.npm_config_argv`.

However, in NPM 7, this feature appears to have been removed. The flags are still not present in `process.argv` (like always) but now `npm_config_argv` is also gone.

The values are now found on `process.env` as individual config values like this:

```js
npm_config_override: 'true',
npm_config_versionnumber: '1.2.3'
npm_config_loglevel: 'error'
```

This presents a few problems:

- Every other NPM config value also has its own `npm_config_` key (like `loglevel` above), so it's impossible to tell which ones were passed as flags
- There's no way to distinguish between flags that were passed with one hyphen vs. two hyphens
- The letter casing (lower/upper/camel) doesn't match the value passed to the script

Is there a workaround for passing flags to a package.json script in NPM 7?

Comment: Since the release of npm 7.x several of `npm_*` environment variables have been removed. Refer to [rfc #0021](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md#downsides) for further details. Note in the [Downsides](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md#downsides) section of that rfc it states: _"Where the `argv` is being parsed in order to determine the command being run, the `npm_command` environ provides a safer approach."_ - so that may be worth exploring.

Comment: @RobC - That's a great lead, thank you. As you said, it looks like `npm_command` should have what I need but currently it only shows a value of `exec` so I assume it's not yet fully implemented. For now I'm using a hack that filters out known `npm_config_` property names. I'll mark as accepted if you'd like to make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the release of npm 7.x several of the `npm_*` prefixed environment variables have been removed. Refer to [rfc #0021](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md#downsides) for further details.

Note, in the [Downsides](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md#downsides) section of that rfc it states:

> *Some modules today use `npm_config_argv`. These will have to be updated to use other means to get this information.*
>
> *Where the argv is being parsed in order to determine the command being run, the `npm_command` environ provides a safer approach.*

Therefore the `npm_command` environment variable may be worth exploring. However, as noted in your comment it currently holds a value of `exec` only which suggests it has not yet been fully implemented.

Answer (score 3):

did you try `--` before providing the arguments to the script?

> Any positional arguments are passed to the specified script. Use `--` to pass --prefixed flags and options which would otherwise be parsed by npm.
>
> For example:
>
> ```sh
> npm run test -- --grep="pattern"
> ```
>
> [*Source*.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script#description)